# GA4 Analytics Reporting API - Fail to push limit

Tags: php, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

Im trying to get analytics from my new GA4-analytics account.
I'm trying the following code, but whatever I do, i get "Error occurred during parsing: Fail to push limit." I dont know what this means.
When I debug whats inside $client, I can see it uses the right service account I created. The Analytics Reporting API is activated.

```
require_once 'autoload.php';

use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\BetaAnalyticsDataClient;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\DateRange;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Dimension;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Metric;


$property_id = 123456789; //property hidden
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/var/www/knto-ga-4-18de552c62e1.json' );

$client=new BetaAnalyticsDataClient();
try {
    $response = $client->runReport([
        'property' => 'properties/' . $property_id,
        'dateRanges' => [
            new DateRange([
                'start_date' => '1daysago',
                'end_date' => 'today',
            ]),
        ],
        'dimensions' => [new Dimension(
            [
                'name' => 'city',
            ]
        ),
        ],
        'metrics' => [new Metric(
            [
                'name' => 'activeUsers',
            ]
        )
        ]
    ]);
}
catch(Exception $e){
    die($e->getMessage());
}

// Print results of an API call.
print 'Report result: ' . PHP_EOL;

foreach ($response->getRows() as $row) {
    print $row->getDimensionValues()[0]->getValue()
        . ' ' . $row->getMetricValues()[0]->getValue() . PHP_EOL;
}
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this error and the solution for me was the files through my repository push/pull where being slightly modified (few bytes shaved off for likely some encoding) and causing this error.

The solution for me was to manually update the following files (in binary mode):

```
/analytics-data/meta-data/V1Beta/AnalyticsDataApi.php
/analytics-data/meta-data/V1Beta/Data.php
```

Double check after upload that the bytes of the file are the same on your local dev box and production.